# SVG filter updates by javascript not consistent across browsers

Tags: javascript, svg, browser

I'm trying to modify the filter of an svg object through javascript.  Mouse over should make the grey shadow turn red.

Problem is that Chrome and Safari don't have any effect, but Firefox does.  I was able to get Safari to do the right thing when I single stepped through the Javascript debugger, so I worry it might be a timing thing with the webkit that is out of my control.

My goal is to find a solution that allows a filter to be updated in javascript by all 3 browsers.

Safari 11.1,
Chrome 65.0.3325.181,
Firefox 59.0.2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="250" height="150">
    <defs>
        <filter id=glow x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feDropShadow dx=2 dy=2 stdDeviation=2 flood-color="#F00" />
        </filter>
        <filter id=shadow x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feDropShadow dx=2 dy=2 stdDeviation=2 flood-color="#888" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g style="filter: url(#shadow)">
        <rect x=50 y=50 width=50 height=50 style="fill: yellow"
            onmouseover="this.parentNode.style.filter = 'url(#glow)'"
            onmouseout="this.parentNode.style.filter = 'url(#shadow)'" />
    </g>
    <g style="filter: url(#shadow)">
        <rect x=150 y=50 width=50 height=50 style="fill: green"
            onmouseover="this.parentNode.style.filter = 'url(#glow)'"
            onmouseout="this.parentNode.style.filter = 'url(#shadow)'" />
    </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Associated Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjeXMJ?editors=1000

Comment: The properties are getting updated in Chrome, http://recordit.co/ToJBRU4aAq. However, there really doesn't seem to be any standard behavior for how JS DOM methods manipulate SVG elements, https://bocoup.com/blog/css-svg-filters-unaccessible-from-elem-style-xlink-href

Comment: Thanks for the adding the video.  I saw the same thing in Safari.  As RicardoAgra points out below, depending on which object you change the filter on, you can get some success.  So, we *can* change filters in some circumstances, just not clear how to make it consistent.  That blog was interesting, but 8 years ago and maybe a version of svg prior... but still interesting, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the .parent selector:

```
onmouseover="this.style.filter = 'url(#glow)'"
```

it works on chrome. hope it helps.

Comment: I can get some partial success on Chrome with setting the <rect> directly, but never with a parent object (<svg> or <g>) as I believe I should be.

Comment: Was there some aspect in that other question that you wanted to draw attention to?

Comment: the -webkit- might be usefull

Comment: Didn't work, tried it before the original post and explored it again with no luck.